# How to install gvSIG on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, gvsig

I am trying to install gvSIG on Ubuntu 16.04. I would prefer to use the package management system, but it seems [this programme has never been packaged](http://joinup.ec.europa.eu/mailman/archives/gvsig-desktop-tsc-pub/2011-August/000585.html).

Therefore I went to the website and downloaded the `.run` file that is labelled for Ubuntu 16.04. Then I tried to run it:

```
$ chmod +x ./gvSIG-desktop-2.3.1-2501-final-lin_ubuntu_16.04-x86_64-standard.run

$ sh ./gvSIG-desktop-2.3.1-2501-final-lin_ubuntu_16.04-x86_64-standard.run
./gvSIG-desktop-2.3.1-2501-final-lin_ubuntu_16.04-x86_64-standard.run: 1: ./gvSIG-desktop-2.3.1-2501-final-lin_ubuntu_16.04-x86_64-standard.run: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

So this does not work either. Are there any other options?

**Update**

As Mario [explains below](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/228359/21532), the `.run` file is an installation executable that must be run directly. That way the installer fires up correctly and, apparently, installs gvSIG (I left all options by default). However, gvSIG itself is not functional the `.run` is done. It outputs the following:

```
$ sh /opt/gvSIG-desktop/gvSIG-desktop-2.3.1/gvSIG.sh 
[...] 
INFO launch Running autorun from plugin  org.gvsig.scripting.app.mainplugin 
/opt/gvSIG-desktop/gvSIG-desktop-2.3.1/gvSIG.sh: 110: [: ==: unexpected operator 
mkdir: missing operand 
Try 'mkdir --help' for more information.
```

The full output is available [here](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/wQ01NY5D).

I understand something else is missing in the installation.

Comment: I think that you also need superuser privileges with 'sudo' to install gvSIG on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have to run:

```
$ ./gvSIG-desktop-2.3.1-2501-final-lin_ubuntu_16.04-x86_64-standard.run
```

without `sh`, because it's not a shell script but a binary.

Running the programme also dispenses the `sh`:

```
$ /path/to/install/folder/gvSIG.sh
```

Comment: Hi Mario, welcome to StackExchange. I was indeed able to run the install script this way, but still I do not get a functional gvSIG installation. Please check the update to the question.

Comment: Just for posterior clarity: It's the same answer, just a different reason. You're explicitly calling it via sh, while the script expects bash or something else (hence the syntax error). sh is linked to dash on ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know you have a portable version. Very useful if you have problems with the installation.

Answer (score -1):

It is important to be sure the .run file has permission to run. Go to the .run file, right-click it and under “Properties”. Check the box to allow the execution of this file.

Comment: Welcome! He already made the file executable by the chmod call seen in the question, so this wouldn't help.